# Why the global scope gets undefined?

Tags: javascript

return in if statement is throwing undefined. why is it so?

```js
var result = 0;
var reminder = 0; 

function sumIntegers(num) {
  console.log(num, reminder, result)
  if(num === 0) {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  } else {
    reminder = num % 10; //9
    result += Math.floor(reminder); //9 
    num = Math.floor(num/10); 
    sumIntegers(num);
  }
}
console.log(sumIntegers(99));
```

my output:

```
99 0 0
9 9 9
0 9 18
18
undefined
```

Comment: `sumIntegers(num);` -> `return sumIntegers(num);`